# Multi filter using select and show the result on table

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple table and want to filter it with multiple select in order to show the result with multiple filters such as Type: Top and Low.

I tried some libraries such as Select UI but I didn’t get the good result.
Please help.

```
<label>Type:</label>
<select ng-model="filterType" ng-options="item.type as item.type for item in samples | unique:'type'">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>


<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="item in samples | filter:filterType">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.type}}</td>
    <td>{{item.status}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6pyh2h1/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `ui-select` and came up with the solution. Here's how.

Added this HTML block for `ui-select`:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="selected.items" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select types...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="type in types">
    <div ng-bind="type | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

for `repeat="type in types"`, I filtered the `samples` array in such a way that I get all the *unique* types (used your included `unique` filter too!):

```
$scope.types = $filter('unique')($scope.samples, 'type')
  .map(function(item) {
    return item.type
  }) // ["Average", "Medium", "Top", "Low"]
```

Finally, the `ng-repeat`. To filter rows on the basis of selection, I used a custom filter. So,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in samples | filter:customFilter">
```

And, `customFilter` function would go something like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(obj) {
  if (!$scope.selected.items.length) return true
  return $scope.selected.items.indexOf(obj.type) > -1
}
```

And, we are done! It was interesting one! :)

[**Here's working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6f7v623g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make multiple filter like that :

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in samples  | filter:{status: filterStatus, type: filterType} ">
```